Maps JavaScript API v3.44 Cannot read properties of undefined ( possible conflict richfaces 3.3.3)
Hellooo! We have a jsf application (Richfaces 3.3.3) in which we have integrated https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js. We just upgraded from version 3.53 (since it has been removed) to version 3.54. Now an error occurs in another part of the application. Could it be due to jquery.js or prototype.js incompatibility? The error is in "ui.package.js" which is inside richfaces. There seems to be a charging problem...
`ui.pack.js:12857 Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'level')
    at A.asSubMenu (ui.pack.js:12857:44)
    at servicestatus.xhtml:187:14050
asSubMenu @ ui.pack.js:12857
(anonymous) @servicestate.xhtml:187`

Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks!
We hope this error does not occur so that everything loads correctly as before
